# Finding the domain of a three variable function

Tags: functions, multivariable-calculus, rational-functions

I have a problem trying to solve the next excersice:

find the domain of the following function,

$f(x,y,z)=\frac{\sqrt{x^2z-3xz^2+3z^3}}{xy-x^2-y^2-1}$

I know that the domain should be:

$Domain=\{(x,y,z)|x^2z-3xz^2+3z^3 \geq 0\} \setminus \{(x,y,z)|xy-x^2-y^2-1 = 0 \} $

The thing is I have some problems finding the x,y for which:

$xy-x^2-y^2-1 = 0$ , It seems like $xy-x^2-y^2-1\neq0$ for all $x,y \in R$, but again I have some problems given the right argument.

I know it might seems a bit easy but I've been struggling for some time with this.

I would really apreciate any advice or hint you can give me.

Answer (score 1):

Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
xy-x^2-y^2-1&=-(x-y/2)^2-3y^2/4-1\\\\
&\le -1\end{align}$$

for all $x$ and $y$.

Hence the denominator of $f(x,y,z)$ can never be zero.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark

Comment: thanks so much that was really hepful, may I ask you something else, using a similar process to see what were the points for which $x^2z-3xz^2+3z^3 \geq 0$ I got that this holds for every $x,z \in R$ so the domain would be $R^3$, right?

Comment: Not quite.  Note that $$3z^3-3xz^2+x^2z=3z(z^2-xz+x^2/3)=3z((z-x/2)^2+x^2/12)\ge 0$$for $z\ge0$.  But for $z<0$, $3z^3-3z^2+x^2z<0$.